# hogan templates defined in html (script or div element) instead of inline javascript

Tags: mustache, icanhaz.js, hogan.js

I would like to swap our template engine from [ICanHas](http://icanhazjs.com) ([Mustache](http://mustache.github.com)) to [Hogan](http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js). ICanHas allows you to define templates in a script block. Is it possible to do this with Hogan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Here's a simple template in a `script` tag:

```
<script id="hogan-tpl" type="text">
    hello {{planet}}
</script>​
```

Here's the minimal JavaScript needed that grabs the template from the `script` element, compiles it with Hogan.js, and renders with the appropriate data before assigning it to the innerHTML of the body:

```
var template = $('#hogan-tpl').html(),
    hello = Hogan.compile(template),
    context = { planet: "world" },
    tpl = hello.render(context);

document.body.innerHTML = tpl;​
```

[Here is it working on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/ztZas/)

Comment: Yep so you can get the template content with $("#").html() the simply compile and use it as you would any other template. Simple. Thank you maxbeatty :)